# Calculate the Average delivery time (days) Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to calculate the average delivery time (in days) of products using `ORM` single query (The reason of using single query is, I've 10000+ records in db and don't want to iterate them over loops). Here is the example of models file, I have:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class ProductEvents(models.Model):
    
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        IN_TRANSIT = ("in_transit", "In Transit")
        DELIVERED = ("delivered", "Delivered")

    product = models.ForiegnKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Status.choices)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

To calculate the delivery time for 1 product is:

```
product = Product.objects.first()
# delivered_date - in_transit_date = days_taken
duration = product.productevent_set.get(status='delivered').created - product.productevent_set.get(status='in_transit').created
```

I'm here to get your help to getting started myself over this so, that I can calculate the average time between all of the Products. I'd prefer it to done in a single query because of the performance.

Comment: Is each product only delivered once? Are there only two related ProductEvents for each Product, the start and end of transit?

Comment: A very good question, for now, let's consider that the product delivers once. There are multiple `ProductEvents` related to one `Product` but these two are base one that will be used to calculate the average delivery time.

Comment: Just edited the delivery time calculation for one product.

Comment: As your output do you just want a single timedelta that is the average delivery time for all products? What do you want to do about products that have not been delivered or even been in transit?

Comment: I want to get an output in an integer having the average duration (days) of all products. For an instance, I want to neglect all the products that have not been delivered yet.

Comment: Neglecting part will also cover the products that has `delivery_exception`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic solution is to annotate each Product with the minimum created time for related events that have the status "in-transit and select the maximum time for events with the delivered status then annotate the diff and aggregate the average of the diffs

```
from django.db.models import Min, Max, Q, F, Avg

Product.objects.annotate(
    start=Min('productevents__created', filter=Q(productevents__status=ProductEvents.Status.IN_TRANSIT)),
    end=Max('productevents__created', filter=Q(productevents__status=ProductEvents.Status.DELIVERED))
).annotate(
    diff=F('end') - F('start')
).aggregate(
    Avg('diff')
)
```

Returns a dictionary that should look like

```
{'diff__avg': datetime.timedelta(days=x, seconds=x)}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's something I wanted to achieve, one another thing that I wanted to know. How can I calculate the Average time in `in_transit`?

Comment: @MuhammadHammad Isn't the average time in transit the same as the average difference between the earliest in transit event and the latest delivered event for each product?

Comment: Sometimes, products get `delivery_exceptions`. In that case, there will be no delivered status.

Comment: There is an event called `delivery_excpetion` for your reference.

Comment: So the average time in transit would be the average of: delivered time minus in-transit time if the product was delivered and exception time minus in-transit time if there was an exception?

Comment: Let me make it more understandable the product delivery time would be the average of: delivered time - in transit time and for about the product stay in transit (delivered or exception time) - in transit time.

Comment: Ahh, I think I got an answer, I just need to add `|` (or) in Q clause of end_time to calculate the product in in_transit.

Comment: So, it would be something like that 
```
end=Max('productevents__created', filter=Q(productevents__status=ProductEvents.Status.DELIVERED) | Q(productevents__status=ProductEvents.Status.Exception))
``` right?

Comment: @MuhammadHammad looks like it would work, you'll need to ensure that a product doesn't have a delivered and an exception or multiple of either or it may get confusing

Comment: hmmm, then we also need to consider the products that has (delivered or exception or neither of these two events)